# Regex to select variations on a pattern

Tags: regex

lets say I have the phrase :

```
www w w w wwwcom com c o m
```

I want to block www, w w w  com (when its not part of another word) and c o m

I can do this by looking for each of the following:

```
www
\bw w w\b
\bcom\b
\bc o m\b
```

However can i combine them into single statements that would search for both www and w w w or com and c o m leaving 2 regular expressions rather than 4?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pipe to or your regex. For example `rega|regb`. In your case it will be:

```
\b((www)|(w w w))\b
```

Answer (score 0):

Strip the white space as part of the match:

www - `\b\s*w\s*w\s*w\s*\b`

com - `\b\s*c\s*o\s*m\s*\b`

both - `\b\s*w\s*w\s*w\s*|\s*c\s*o\s*m\s*\b`

Answer (score 0):

Sabuj Hassan's answer is the only way to get precisely what you've specified. However, if you're okay with also matching `ww w` and `w ww`, then you could use:

```
\bw ?w ?w\b
```

This will allow *up to one* space between each pair of letters (tabs, multiple spaces, etc will not be matched).

The same can be done for `com`. You can combine this with the `|` approach to get one regex:

```
\b(w ?w ?w|c ?o ?m)\b
```

David Haney's answer (using `\s*`) is similar, but will match "phrases" that have any combination of spaces and tabs between letters. For instance, `w\t\t\t \tw    w` (where `\t` is a tab character) will be considered a match.

Answer (score 0):

\b(w\s*w\s*w|c\s*o\s*m)\b

This matches:
www
com
ww w
co m
w w w
c o m

in:
www.something => matches www
wwwword       => no matches
word.com      => matches com
wordcom       => no matches

doesn't match:
wwwe
ewww
come
ecom